# Wordpress comment section disappeared

Tags: php, wordpress

I have no idea what happened, but all the posts have no comment or "leave a reply" section at the end of the post.

**I tried**

1. disabling all plugins using FTP
2. changing the theme
3. copying all the root files of default wordpress install + includes folder and replacing the current ones
4. Installing wordpress again and uploading wp-contents folder to it... and importing everything using the provided wordpress import tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in the back end of your WP site to see if comments have been disabled on the post itself. You can see this by going into the post, then clicking on "Screen Options" in the upper right corner. Click the "Discussion" box, which will display the discussion options below your wysiwyg. Make sure that "Allow Comments" is checked.

Comment: Also, did your blog once have the option for comments, and they suddenly disappeared? Or is this happening off a base install?

Comment: It did have the option but it turned out that the plugin "facebook comments" disables wp comments in all posts and hides "discussion" block, although I looked for both "allow comments" and "discussion" I couldn't find them, I looked again now and saw them as I stated in my answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

OMG, that was so stupid, am sorry for this question
One of the plugins I tested and disabled (called facebook spider comments) has automatically disabled comments in all posts and hidden the admin "discussion" block!

when I tried to edit one of the posts I looked for the choice "Allow comments" and couldn't find it, I looked in "screen options" for discussion but I think I simply overlooked it!

I really apologize for this mess